# Why is Blasius solution dependent on eta?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

In many textbooks, and derivations of the Blasius solution (including in his original paper), there's never an explanation to why $f$ is a function only of $\eta$, $f=f(\eta)$. For what I understand, the solution starts with the equations

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = 0\\
u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + v\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} =
\nu \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}
\end{cases}
$$

And for self-similarity reasons we assume that $u = u\left(\frac{y}{\delta(x)}\right) = u(\eta)$, where $\eta \propto \frac{y}{\delta}$. Also because of scaling reasons we use the momentum equation to derive

$$
u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \sim \nu \frac{\partial ^{2} u}{\partial y^{2}} \; \rightarrow  \; \frac{U_\infty}{x} \sim \frac{\nu}{\delta ^{2}} \; \rightarrow  \; \delta ( x) \sim \sqrt{\frac{\nu x}{U_\infty}} $$

Where we can now define

$$\eta = y\sqrt{\frac{U_\infty}{\nu x}}$$

We also introduce the stream function $\psi(x,y)$, which is defined so that

$$
\frac{\partial \psi }{\partial y} = u ,\quad -\frac{\partial \psi }{\partial x} = v
$$

In such a way that the continuity equation is already satisfied when using $\psi(x,y)$. But realizing that $\psi = \int u\ dy \sim U_\infty \delta \sim U_\infty \sqrt{\nu x/U_\infty}$, we can nondimensionalize it by defining

$$f = \frac{\psi}{U_\infty \sqrt{\nu x/U_\infty}}$$.

The only thing that I don't understand in this derivation, is why is $f$ a function of $\eta$? I tried many times to use the chain rule to prove that $\frac{df}{d\eta} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial \eta}$, but I simply couldn't. If someone can help me, I'd be very grateful.